# Conditional Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I'm tying to understand how I can have a conditional promise, without repeating everything inside the .then function again.

For example:

```
if (cameraFilmType == "Standard")
```

Then I don't want to call the addImageFilter function

```
if (cameraFilmType == "Vintage")
```

Then i do want to call the addimageFilter function.

I still want to run everything inside the .then in both cases, but i need the option to use .then as the addImageFilter function is async. How can i do this without repeating the code in .then twice?

```
    factory.addImageFilter(imageData, cameraFilmType).then(function (newImg) {
        $scope.imageData = newImg;
        //Do loads of stuff
    });
```

Comment: How do you write `if (x) then(aValue) else then(bValue)` without repeating `then`?